# apply class to span if inline style contains color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that is using an API to extract raw information from a website. This raw information has all of it's inline styles still intact, so what I'd like to do is add a class to a `span` if it contains an inline style with the style being `background-color: #345678`. Is this possible with Javascript/jQuery?

My current method for removing the styling is:

```
$(".card").removeAttr("style");
```

and I tried using this code for adding a class, but it didn't seem to be effective:

```
$('span[style*="background-color"][style*="#345678"]').addClass('alignleft');
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Check the [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close on your implementation:

```
$('span[style*="background-color"][style*="#345678"]').addClass('alignleft');
```

But you need to put them both together: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/t9dLpo9k/2/)

```
$("span[style*='background-color: #345678']");
```

Comment: good answer - you could make it somewhat more robust by stripping spaces / lowercase for comparisons etc.

Comment: @ToniLeigh I agree, I wrote it with a, slight, cringe, putting in the hard coded strings, but I figured it would be good to get them on the right track.  Feel free to update the fiddle if you want.